# A human 10x faster at thinking or reacting than the quickest human; could they catch an arrow?

Tags: science-based, humans, super-powers

Let us say that someone is 10 times faster at thinking or reacting than the quickest human, assume that they can survive these feats and their muscles can perform them and their senses detect them.I have two questions would this person be able to block or catch arrows and what would this look like to a normal human? Feel free to add anything else cool you think they could achieve.

Comment: Could you make your question more focused? At the moments it's going to get voted closed for being too broad or too opinion based. Try breaking your ideas down into multiple questions. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: nzaman is this closer to what you were thinking?

Comment: Let's put it this way, in several ball games, e.g., baseball, cricket, balls have been thrown at 100km/h which comes to about 30 m/s. These balls have been hit, and the resulting flying ball caught. Assuming that speed remained unchanged, it is possible to catch a 30 m/s ball. An arrow flies at around 60m/s, so it's possible for even a normal, well-trained person to catch it. A quick google search could give you the answer in 5 minutes. While I am not discouraging you from asking questions here, questions that are easily answered with a yes/no or internet search are not well received.

Comment: Catching a ball in a game is fundamentally different from catching an arrow.  What you're really doing when catching a ball is moving your hand in front of it - this is a relatively large time frame from throw (which you can anticipate the flight of) to intercept.  And arrow is a weapon - put your hand in front of it and you don't really catch it - you have an arrow through your hand !  The window to catch an arrow is smaller for this reason - you must time your motion to catch the part behind the tip.

Comment: @StephenG: An arrow is also a lot longer, so you have a larger time margin to catch it

Comment: I would fire a very fragile arrow at them, maybe something hollow, in the hopes that even in they catch it the arrow will snap and possibly still wing them, preferably something with poison in it. ... lol

Comment: There is a big difference between asking whether someone could catch an arrow and whether they could _reliably_ catch an arrow. Every skill, no matter how practiced, can still fail you. I don't see a time when someone is so certain they will catch an arrow that it is beneficial to do that rather than just step out of the way (a lot easier). So, are you asking whether it is possible or whether it is a viable tactic?

Comment: I, for one, might be satisfied with the ability to reliably bat the arrow and knock it off course so it didn't hit me, especially if I didn't care about anyone who might be standing beside me.  If someone did grab an arrow coming at them, could they stop it or would it rip out of their grip and go on to hit them anyway.

Comment: If the average speed of arrow is 150 mph, then person thinking 10x faster would experience the arrow flying by at 15 mph (24km/h) speed. Imagine someone bicycling by and holding an arrow. Would you be able to grab it? I think it is possible but far from easy. Also, if the shot comes unexpected, the arrow has already covered 20% of the distance before the sound of the bowstring reaches you.

Comment: *Mythbusters* tested for the human ability to catch arrows in midflight. Results: it wasn't possible. The catcher needed to be be superhumanly fast. From what i remember I would concur with @CongenitalOptimist barely possible. Grabbing 24 km/h objects in flight will be at the limits of a ten times faster superhuman. Possible but with great difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming such a thing (the 10x speedup, I mean) is actually possible it would mean signals on neurons travel much faster and synaptic neurotransmitters bridge the gap in (much) less time.

In such a situation, even if bone/muscle infrastructure doesn't change much, it is very likely such a (super)man would be able to pick an arrow in flight.

As noted in comments there already are people who, through long training, are able to stop an arrow. These men, however, are pulling the feat in a completely different way. They, through training, learn exactly how much time it will take the arrow to be in the right position and send their hand to the "meeting point" just in time, like a pianist sending his fingers to hit keys in the exact time frame.

Fact is all these (and many other) gestures are "open loop": brain evaluates situation and start gesture; after that it's not possible to modify gesture because, simply, there's no time for feedback to go back to brain.

A sizable signal speedup, like that you envision, would completely change the game and allow direct feedback. This means gestures can be more precise and "reasoned" (in the sense gesture can be modified "on the flight").

Note: this speedup *could* allow arrow-stopping to be used in actual combat situation; what "normal(??) human" arrow catchers rely on is exact knowledge of where the arrow is going (archer is compliant), it wouldn't be possible if archer is free to chose his target.

Answer (score 2):

A regular human can deflect or block an arrow with a sword after a decent training, I just spent about 15 minutes on youtube watching videos about it. The key moment is a duration of arrow flight - it must be long enough. If your character is 10 times faster, it will be relatively easy for him, especially after a training.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QLpYDQ0FSA - the video is about man trying to deflect an arrow with the sword. To the end of this 7 minute long video his chances to hit an arrow increases significantly. Probably he hits it by chance, yet still a short training helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, while it is possible for standard humans to catch arrows, that's only true up to a certain bow strength.

So in order to actually answer this question, we would need to know the speed at which the arrow was travelling, because, guess what, that really, really varies depending on type of bow, arrow and the like.

Like a 20-30 pound bow, sure, a normal human with training can do  that, but something stronger means more speed and it's harder/impossible to do. Maybe be precise about the speed/type of arrows? At 10 times the normal speed, I would think even the higher range ones would be possible, up to a point.

But speed is not the only factor. Force is another. The super compound bows available today are super fast. And super fast means lots of energy and force. While your 10xs speed humans might be able to catch the arrow, it doesn't mean they will go away unscathed. In baseball, a glove is worn to protect the hand, but the ball moves more slowly, and the surface area is different. Friction, with catching a long arrow, is going to be an issue. Your humans might get hurt. (Not as big of a deal at under 30 pound draw, but even then, friction burns do happen).

Oh hey, and as to how it might look--here's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmvHGmKITp4).
And something [on combat conditions and ninjas catching it](https://mythresults.com/return-of-the-ninja) from mythbusters